# How to manually code the "View this email in your browser"?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, email

I am writing a mailer on my rails app. I have coded the html/css part but I'd like to add the ability for a user to open the mail in the browser.

How do I do that ? What to put on that link ? Can I do it without services likes sendgrid/mailchimp ?

Comment: The only thing I could think of, is converting the email to HTML and hosting it on your server - then just link there. :)

Answer (score 0):

Would this be a public Email for everyone like a newsletter everyone can subscribe? Then you can host it on your server and link it easily. 
When you want to send personal emails which are unique the the user then you need much more. To write code all by yourself would be too much. 
Use a framework or even even consider to use a service.

[This](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) might help.

Answer (score -1):

If your sending a HTML Email then the following can be put in the header  
<a href=”{{ mirror }}”>View this email in your browser.
Or footer or wherever you like. [Common look and feel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xhrx9.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).